Apache Superset - Conditional Formatting on a column based on the values of another column?
I am using a Pivot Table v2 in Apache Superset. I have two metric columns: 'Cost' and 'Percentage Diff.' (I'll refer to this as '%').
My goal is: for every row, the background color of the 'Cost' cell depends on the value of the '%' cell.
Example:

Customer A has '100$' in Cost, and '+30%' in '%'. The '100$' should have a green background due to the +30%.
Customer B has '300$' in Cost, and '-15%' in '%'. The '300$' should have a (fainter) red background due to the -15%.

With the current implementation of Pivot Table, as far as I can tell, conditional formatting is only available based on the value of the cell being formatted itself. Is there any plugin or does anyone have any general pointers into how I could solve this problem? I am more than happy to look into the code and modify it, although I'm experiencing difficulties due to lack of documentation of the codebase...
Thanks in advance and all the best!
